# How to fix "the App Engine SDK is out-of-date"?

Tags: java, google-app-engine

Many years ago, I used "**appengine-java-sdk-1.9.22**" to build my webapp which uses some datastore

Now, I updated my app on eclipse & when deployed, it said:

```
Unable to update:
com.google.appengine.tools.admin.HttpIoException: Error posting to URL: https://appengine.google.com/api/appversion/deploy?app_id=speaklikewater&version=1&
401 Unauthorized
Your version of the App Engine SDK is out-of-date. Please update your SDK at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/download#appengine_sdk and your Maven plugin, if necessary, according to the instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/tools/maven

    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.OAuth2ServerConnection.doHandleSendErrors(OAuth2ServerConnection.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:373)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:317)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:296)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.LoggingClientDeploySender.send(LoggingClientDeploySender.java:47)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:1134)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.deploy(AppVersionUpload.java:982)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.commit(AppVersionUpload.java:865)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFilesTransaction(AppVersionUpload.java:223)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:197)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:580)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:65)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:433)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:158)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
```

Now, I used the almost lastest  "sdk appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54" (see the picture below), but still get the same error

[image]

Note: 
I changed to new SDK by going to Window==> Preferences==> Google ===>App Engine & selected "appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54"

If I use "appengine-java-sdk-1.9.64", I get this error "Internal Error":

[image]

SO, I decided to use "appengine-java-sdk-1.9.54" because some people also have "Internal Error" & they tried using lower version & it worked.

I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: The last version it's 1.9.64 (it appears on the screenshot you sent, but you chose 1.9.54). 1.9.54 it's [dated](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/release-notes#june_15_2017) June 15th of 2017 , so try to update it and tell me if it worked.

Comment: @Iñigo, I tried & I got  "Internal Error", see my updated question

Comment: there is not enough information about your case to work with. What are the details when you're using .64? The errors you get while using .54 tell you to update. Maybe you can try using .63 or .62 (and so on) but the error specifically says you need to update from .54, you can also try to update Maven too.

Comment: I found this [Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/110066569) where a guy had a similar issue as you (using Eclipse and a old java version). In the last comment you have the "solution".

Comment: @Iñigo, I tried ".63" & got the same Internal errors

Comment: Please read the public issue, it's explained there

Comment: @Iñigo, i tried to intall latest eclipse & google cloud but seem like they don't use Google Pluin like many years ago, so there is no "Deploy" button on eclipse. Do you have a link to show how to convert old appengine project to new one?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the Public Issue [[1]](https://issuetracker.google.com/110066569), Google Plugin is deprecated, you need to migrate [[2]](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/migrating-gpe#app_engine_standard) to Google Tools.

Here you have the quickstart for you to have a better idea on how GAE currently works with Eclipse [[3]](https://cloud.google.com/eclipse/docs/quickstart).